# Using mail and password to authenticate via the REST API [Firebase] in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a live chat application using FCM. I have a login screen and I want to login using my login screen rather than firebase provided UI. So thats why I need some rest API for login and as a success I need also the "FirebaseAuth.getInstance()".

Please some one give some suggestion to solve it.

Comment: What issues are you having storing login information in the database itself instead of FirebaseAuth? Please show some code that you're working with

Comment: Instead of " startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),
                    SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
            );" I  need an Rest API for authenticate and login in firebase.

Comment: Almost all of Firebase  already is a REST API. Are you using the Realtime database, or Cloud Firestore?

Comment: I am using Firebase realtime Database and I need Authenticate Users using API

Comment: Okay, and have you tried to use the `equalTo` method on a DatabaseReference or Snapshot to check for existence of your accounts?

Comment: if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {

            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),
                    SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
            );

           } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                            .getCurrentUser()
                            .getDisplayName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            displayChatMessages();
           }

Comment: I have not use the equalTo method.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question... Remove FirebaseUI from your project. Then you have FirebaseAuth still... If that's the case, I don't understand what problems you have with writing your own layout code and button events. Especially since the documentation covers exactly what you want. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need some rest API for login

Firebase already is a REST API. The client SDK is a wrapper around it

> I want to login using my login screen

Okay, define a layout with some input boxes and a login button. Don't use the AuthUI project

> as a success I need also the "FirebaseAuth.getInstance()"

You need that before you can even sign in, not just a success. For example, within the `onCreate` method

```
this.mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

> using mail and password

Read the documentation, you'll find the method named [`signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html)

You can even [copy code directly out of the examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)